# GetCustomAttributes(true) not returning attributes from a types parent?

Tags: c#, validation, reflection

I have the following (greatly simplified) classes:

```
public class Customer {
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="Required", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(ResourcesCommon.ValidationStrings))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class SalesCustomer : Customer {
    ...
}
```

I have some validation code that loops through SalesCustomer properties. Each property is evaluated with this:

```
 var validators = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true);
```

The problem is that the Required attribute is not getting returned when I look at the LastName property on the SalesCustomer type but it does work fine when I look at the Customer type.  This is confusing since the GetCustomerAttribute() method explicitly wants a boolean indicating that the inherited attributes will be returned.

Comment: Does `SalesCustomer` shadow the property?

Comment: Is `Customer` required as a concrete type? I would make `abstract class Customer` with `abstract string LastName` getter/setter; decorate with `RequiredAttribute` ...

Comment: No. I do have a couple of other properties that override the parent class but not the ones that are causing me issues.

Comment: No, I can't abstract Customer here.  It used throughout my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it will only return attributes from **overridden** parent members, not shadowed parent members.

Make the base property `virtual` and the child property `overrrides`.

Comment: Thanks.  Ran some unit tests to verify this and it seems to be the case.